# If $P(A)=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ then find $P(P(A)-A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $P(A)=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ then find $P(P(A)-A)$.

note that $P$ is the set of subsets of $A$.

**My solution**:I find the answer same as $P(A)$. Am I right?

I asked this because I had a disscustion about this with my friend.

Comment: This can be checked in a mechanical way by three steps. No collection of sets exceeds four members either. So it should be quick.

Comment: yes, it is. $P(A)-A =\{\{\emptyset\}\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not quite.

- Since $P(A) = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$ has $2$ elements, we know that $A$ must have $\log_2 2 = 1$ element. In particular, we know that $A = \{\varnothing\}$.
- Now since $\varnothing \in A$ and $\varnothing \in P(A)$, it follows that the empty set is not an element of their difference so that $P(A) - A = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$.
- Finally, since $P(A) - A$ contains $1$ element, we know that its power set must have $2^1 = 2$ elements. Thus, we conclude that:
  $$
  P(P(A) - A) = \{\varnothing, P(A) - A\} = \{\varnothing, \{\{\varnothing\}\}\}
  $$
  which, to be clear, is indeed different from:
  $$
  P(A) = \{\varnothing, A\} = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}
  $$